# React-konva, Animation comes from the center of Element

Tags: konvajs, react-spring, react-konva

Now I working on react-konva library and using @react-spring/konva for applying the animation for the element. I have the question about the way to make the animation start from the center point of element, I have tried with the suggestion set the offsetX and offsetY is a half of width and height but maybe it not work nicely when the first time I start the animation and next times are correct. Is there a way to make offsetX and offsetY not affect the current position of the element. Anyone can help me check this issue my code at: https://codesandbox.io/s/type-animation-pop-rfjyzj